# Leer un archivo de notas de alumnos, y reescribirlo en otro archivo mostrando los promedios

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un código que me permita leer un archivo CSV que consta de 3 campos (legajo, nombre, notas) y escribir en otro archivo los promedios, también en formato CSV. Quedaría: Legajos, nombres y promedios.

En el archivo de entrada, se pueden repetir alumnos y legajos en distintas líneas, ya que un mismo alumno puede tener más de una nota. En el de salida, no.

Aclaración: Este código se lo presente a mi profesor, y el error que me destaco fue que cargaba todo el archivo en memoria. Textualmente: *Cargaste todo el archivo en tres listas. Esto es un error gravisimo*.

¿Cómo puedo evitar caer en ese error?

Adjunto código:

```
#Tenemos un archivo para leer un grupo de alumnos,sus legajos y sus notas
#las consignas son: En primer lugar, escribir en otro archivo todos los alumnos, con sus nombres y promedios correspondientes
#en segundo lugar, mostrar un listado de los diez mejores promedios(tmb hacerlo con las notas en si)

"Primero, abriremos el archivo"

try:
    archivo=open("NOMBRES ALUMNOS.txt","r")
    archivo2=open("Salida Alumnos.txt","w")
    """Posterior a abrir el codigo, lo que haremos sera crear listas correspondientes a los distintos campos a grabar en destino"""
    
    LU=[]
    nombres=[]
    notas=[]
    
    """leemos el archivo mediante un for"""
    for linea in archivo:
        linea=linea.rstrip("\n")
        datos=linea.split(";")
        """separamos los datos con un split en el punto y coma"""
        
        LU.append(datos[0])
        nombres.append(datos[1])
        notas.append(int(datos[2]))
        
    """appendeamos los datos correspondientes a cada lista, destacando que las notas se pasan a entero para operar matematicamente dsps con ellas"""
    nombres_sin_repetir=set(nombres.copy())
    """Para borrar repetidos, usamos conjuntos"""
    notas_por_alumno=[[] for i in range(len(nombres_sin_repetir))]
    
    """Aca le daremos notas correspondientes a cada alumno"""
    for i in range(len(nombres)):
        if nombres[i] in nombres_sin_repetir:
            ubicacion=nombres.index(nombres[i])
            notas_por_alumno[ubicacion].append(notas[i])
            
    promedios=[]
    """Como el formato de salida nos pide dos decimales como minimo/maximo, en caso de faltarnos uno lo agregaremos, y en caso opuesto truncaremos el numero en 2 decimales"""
    for i in range(len(notas_por_alumno)):
        prom=sum(notas_por_alumno[i])/len(notas_por_alumno[i])
        if len(str(prom))>5:
            prom=str(prom)[:4]
        elif len(str(prom))<4:
            prom=str(prom)+"0"
               
        promedios.append(str(prom))
    
    """Creamos un diccionario para acopilar todos los datos, y lo ordenamos mediante sort y una funcion lambda"""        
    dic=[{"legajo":LU[i],"names":nombres[i],"notes":str(notas[i]),"promedios":promedios[i]} for i in range(len(nombres_sin_repetir))]
    dic.sort(key=lambda x:x.get("promedios"),reverse=True)
            
    """Imprimos por pantalla los datos, y los escribimos en el archivo de salida"""
    for i in range(len(dic)):
        print(dic[i].get("legajo"),dic[i].get("names"),dic[i].get("notes"),dic[i].get("promedios"))
        archivo2.write(str(dic[i].get("legajo")+";"+dic[i].get("names"))+";"+dic[i].get("notes")+";"+dic[i].get("promedios")+"\n")

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No se ha encontrado el archivo")
except OSError:
    print("Falla sistemica")

finally:
    try:
        archivo.close()
        archivo2.close()
    except NameError:
        pass

"""cerramos todo"""
```

Comment: En lugar de hacer 3 listas puedes crear un diccionario y de esa forma también podrías ir agregando las notas, si el alumno ya existe en tu diccionario se agrega la nota, si no, se crea la llave y se agrega la primera nota. Otra forma sería creando un `dataframe` con pandas

Answer (score 1):

**Nota:** Gracias a respuesta de Candid Moe, pude entender que es un legajo, así que logré escribir esta respuesta.

---

#### Cual es el error y por que es relevante

No estoy en la cabeza de tu profesor, pero si vió lo mismo que yo, es que estás cargando todo el csv en memoria y luego calculando el promedio.

¿Pero realmente necesitas tener cada legajo, alumno y nota del csv cargado en memoria?
En realidad, no, pues lo que te importa es la suma de las notas y la cantidad de notas, que son los datos que usarás para calcular el promedio.

Esto para mi debería decirtelo tu profesor, pero considera que pasa si el csv pesa 10 gb. La memoria no daría para cargar todo el archivo en memoria. De ahí el que sea un tema a considerar para archivos grandes sobre todo.

#### Idea

Lo que haría yo, es usar un diccionario de este estilo:

```
{legajo:
     {nombre del alumno:
          {
           "total_notas":0,
           "cantidad_notas":0
          }
      ...
     }
 ...
}
```

Es decir, por cada legajo, habría un diccionario de alumnos, y cada alumno tendría un diccionario donde se almacene la suma de las notas y la cantidad de notas.

Luego, al recorrer el csv, se obtiene el legajo, el alumno, se suma la nota a las demas notas y incrementamos el contador en 1.
Esta tecnica, a diferencia de cargar todas las notas en una lista y calcular el promedio con eso, ahorra más memoria, ya que en ningún momento existen en simultaneo todas las notas del csv.

La implementación de esto sería:

```
legajos = {}

csv = open("archivo.csv")

for line in csv:
    legajo, alumno, nota = line.rstrip("\n").split(";")
    nota = int(nota)

    if(legajo not in legajos):
        legajos[legajo] = {}

    if(alumno not in legajos[legajo]):
        legajos[legajo][alumno] = {"total_notas":0, "cantidad_notas":0}
    
    legajos[legajo][alumno]["total_notas"] += nota
    legajos[legajo][alumno]["cantidad_notas"] += 1

for legajo, alumnos in legajos.items():
    for alumno, data in alumnos.items():
        promedio = data["total_notas"] / data["cantidad_notas"]

        print(legajo, alumno, promedio, sep=";")
```

**Nota** Adaptar este código para que escriba todo en otro csv es tarea para la casa.

Comment: Luego llega el profesor y dice: "Para calcular el promedio, descarte la peor nota del alumno" :-)

Comment: @CandidMoe Eso tiene una solución usando esta estrategia. Solo hay que crear un "campo" mas en el diccionario llamado "nota_mas_baja" y si la ultima nota guardada es la más grande que la nueva nota, guardamos esa nota. Cuando calculamos el promedio, restamos a la suma esa nota y restamos 1 al contador.

Comment: Luego el profesor te pide la distribución estandar ... ja, ja!!!

Comment: No se que es eso. Pero no creo que un profesor sea tan malo como para encargar algo que requiere cargar todos los datos en memoria sin cargar los datos en memoria. Es como pedir un vaso de agua sin agua.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es "¿Cómo procesar el archivo sin cargarlo entero a memoria?".

El patrón usual es leer el archivo línea por línea, acumulando la información de inmediato. En este caso, nos interesa obtener la siguiente estructura:

```
legajos
  + math
      + alumno 1: nota1, nota2, ....
      + alumno 2: nota1, nota2, ....
  + bio
      + alumno 1: nota1, ...
  + soc
      ...
```

O sea, una colección de legajos (o cursos). Por cada curso, una lista de alumnos. Por cada alumno, la lista de sus notas.

Una manera de representar esta información es usando un diccionario con llave "legajo" y cuyo valor sea otro diccionario "alumnos". Este último tiene por llave el nombre del alumno y por valor la lista de sus notas.

La información viene en un formato como este:

```
mat;juan;5
mat;ana;6
bio;juan;6
bio;juan;7
bio;harry;4
soc;juan;5
soc;harry;5
soc;harry;6
```

El código que implemente es

```
legajos = {}
with open("notas.csv","r") as notas:

    #  Procesamos el archivo de entrada línea por línea

    for linea in notas:

        legajo, nombre, notas = linea.split(";")

        #  Nos aseguramos que exista una entrada
        #  para el legajo.

        if legajo not in legajos:
            #  Inicializar con un diccionario vacio de alumnos
            legajos[legajo] = {} 

        alumnos = legajos[legajo]

        #  Nos aseguramos de que exista una entrada para 
        #  el alumno.

        if nombre not in alumnos:
            alumnos[nombre] = []

        #  Finalmente, agregar la nota a su lista

        alumnos[nombre].append(int(notas))


for legajo, alumnos in legajos.items():
    print(f"Legajo {legajo}:")
    for alumno, notas in alumnos.items():
        print(f"  {alumno} {sum(notas) / len(notas)}")
    print()
```

produce:

```
Legajo mat:
  juan 5.0
  ana 6.0

Legajo bio:
  juan 6.5
  harry 4.0

Legajo soc:
  juan 5.0
  harry 5.5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Conclusión**

Puedes adaptar el código para que grabe en el archivo de salida.